# Hacer transparente espacio entre ion-items

Tags: ionic

tengo una lista ionic, y quiero que entre cada ion-item haya un espacio de 15 px, color transparent, de manera de "ver el fondo" de la pantalla en el espacio entre los ion-item.
He probado de todas las maneras, pero no funciona, les agreadeceré si me pueden ayudar. Muchas gracias !

```
<ion-list >
  <ion-item ng-repeat="respuesta in respuestas"
    item="respuesta" ng-click="clicker(respuesta)"
    style="background: violet; border: 15px none transparent !important;">
      <h5 class="item-text-wrap" style="color: white">{{respuesta.detalle}}</h5>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

***Si le pongo color en lugar de transparent, funciona.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estás confundiendo border con margin: el borde no tiene `background`, por lo que no puede ser transparente.

La solución es sencilla: añadir un margen entre cada elemento:

```css
div {
 width:200px;
 background-color: red;
}
li {
  background: violet;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li>uno</li>
<li>dos</li>
<li>tres</li>
<li>cuatro</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Perfecto!

Comment: @Guille Si la respuesta te ayuda, puedes *aceptarla*, marcando el *check* que hay justo debajo de las flechas de voto. Así la pregunta aparece como *respondida*